# Can't clone Google Source Repository on MacOS 10

Tags: git, macos, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos

When I call

```
gcloud source repos clone my-service --project=tools-project
```

inside the Cloud Shell I can successfully clone the `my-service` repository from Google Source Repository.

However when I call the same command on MacOS I get the following error:

```
Cloning into '/Users/XXX/my-service'...
fatal: remote error: PERMISSION_DENIED The caller does not have permission
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '[u'git', u'clone', u'https://source.developers.google.com/p/tools-project/r/my-service', u'/Users/XXX/my-service', u'--config', u'credential.helper=', u'--config', u'credential.helper=!gcloud auth git-helper --account=XXX@XXX.io --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

I am logged in with the same user on the website and on the computer. Where could the error be?

Comment: What credential helper is configured: `git config --list --system`? Clear the credential helper: `git config --system --unset credential.helper`. Set credential helper for MacOS: `git config credential.helper gcloud.sh`

Comment: Can you try running `gcloud init` to create a new configuration and set up local authentication? Furthermore, ensure that the correct account was used by running `gcloud auth login` and check in your IAM permissions that the account you are using has the proper permissions to pull code from the Cloud Source Repositories.

Comment: @JohnHanley When I type `git config --list --system` I find nothing about credentials. When I type `git config credential.helper gcloud.sh` I get the error message `fatal: not in a git directory`. I can't clone the repo, hence I am not inside a Git directory.

Comment: @JKleinne I have already tried it with a new configuration. That didn't work either. I am logged in as the right user. Since I can pull code inside the cloud shell I guess the permissions should be fine.

Comment: Use `git config --global credential.helper gcloud.sh` to enable the option for all git projects. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: @JohnHanley I did that and I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: The only thing left is that you did not install and configure `git` correctly on your system (or something broke later). Note global commands are not part of a .git project, so I don't know how you were able to get the same error message. Make sure that you are using the lastest version of Git and follow this setup: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup Then run `gcloud init`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have appended a `.bak` to the following files:

```
 - .git-credentials 
 - .gitconfig 
 - .gitcookies
```

Now it is working.

P.S.: In the end I have deleted the files.